# Pinned shortcut in MFU (Most Frequency Used) Start menu after NSIS setup

Tags: nsis

A NSIS created deployment setup, installs two executable. After setup, one of them appears in the MFU (Most Frequency Used) list of the start menu. But I don't that.

Is it possible to remove this link or prevent it during install? I have found this [document from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but is very difficult to code this (my knowable is .NET/C#). Or maybe is it possible with NSIS? All tips are welcome.

Comment: This happens on a XP, Vista or 7 machine and not Win8 I'm assuming since you are talking about the start MENU?

Comment: Does this application set a explicit AppUserModelID?

Comment: @anders thank you. I see this happening on Windows 7 and Windows 2008 machines. About AppUserModelID, i don't know.

Comment: If it does have one you need to add a entry under NoStartPageAppUserModelIDs. There is no really easy way to check other than the source code, though http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker does list them in its taskbar inspector...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `WriteRegStr` to write the NoStartPage value but it is usually not something you should set explicitly except if this .exe is some kind of generic host program for plugin modules.

Is it possible that you just tested the program on this particular machine so many times that the program ended up on the MFU list?

There is no official API to add things to the MFU list and NSIS does not do anything to try to get the program listed there...

Comment: Indeed, there's not good solution or API available to prevent this. Thank you for the replies.

Comment: Btw, NoStartPage works only on Windows XP and Windows Vista. It is broken on Windows 7 and later.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Win7 has some NoStartPage entries by default and they probably work, or do you have some link to a MSKB article confirming that it is broken?

Comment: I've tested the NoStartPage but it doesn't response on Windows 7. All this will be confirmed in some documents and internet sites, which unfortunately is.